# Just because a program has a GUI does it mean it will crash in windows docker?

Tags: .net, windows, azure, docker

I am trying to take an existing application that is launched via command line and does in fact have a GUI inside a docker container. I am getting an Invalid Operation Exception upon launch most likely because this program launches a GUI. Is it fair to say this is just not possible because Azure Windows Docker containers do not support GUIs? I understand the concept of not needing a GUI and not being able to RDP into a container to use a GUI, but if a program happens to have a GUI will it not run at all?

Comment: not related to Azure. Generally speaking containers are GUI-less. It might be possible to install xserver onto linux containers? I'm not sure

Comment: Linux containers with a GUI do not need a X server, Skype, Chrome, Spotify work fine in containers, see https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using xvfb to run GUI application in container like for example Chrome browser with automatic Selenium tests.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb